# Stata: perform a foreach loop to calculate kappa across a large data file

Tags: foreach, stata

I have a data file in Stata with 50 variables

```
   j-r-hp   j-p-hp  j-m-hp   p-c-hp  p-r-hp  p-p-hp   p-m-hp ... etc,
```

I want to perform a weighted kappa between pairs, so that the first might be

```
  kap j-r-hp j-p-hp, wgt(w2)
```

and the next would be

```
  kap j-r-hp j-m-hp, wgt(w2)
```

I am new to Stata. Is there a straightforward way to use a loop for this, like a `foreach` loop?

Comment: Hyphens are not legal in Stata variable names (hyphens are used to construct variable lists). You could use underscores (eg, `j_r_hp`).

Comment: An unusual amount of activity for a Stata question here, but please be reminded that asking for code without showing any attempt, is considered off-topic by many.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable names are not legal names in Stata, so I've changed the hyphens to underscores in the example below. Also, I don't know what it means to 'perform a weighted kappa', so my answer uses random normal variables and the `corr[elate]` command. You can use the results that Stata leaves behind in `r()` (see `return list`) to gather the results for the separate analyses.

The idea is to gather the variables in a list using a `local`, then to loop over each element in that list (but skipping the repeated pairs using `continue`). If you have many variables with structured names, you could instead use `ds`, which leaves `r(varlist)` in `r()`.Have a look at the help file for macros (`help macro` and `help extended_fcn`), especially the section on 'Macro extended functions for parsing'. Hope this helps.

```
clear
set obs 100
local vars j_r_hp j_p_hp j_m_hp p_c_hp p_r_hp p_p_hp p_m_hp
foreach var of local vars   {
    gen `var'=rnormal()
}

forval ii=1/`: word count `vars''   {
    forval jj=1/`: word count `vars''   {
        if `ii'<`jj'    continue
        corr `: word `ii' of `vars'' `: word `jj' of `vars''
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the user-written command `tuples` (run `ssc install tuples`):

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

set obs 100
local vars j_r_hp j_p_hp j_m_hp p_c_hp p_r_hp p_p_hp p_m_hp

foreach var of local vars   {
    gen `var' = abs(round(rnormal()*100))
}

*----- what you want -----

tuples `vars', min(2) max(2)
forvalues i = 1/`ntuples' {
    display _newline(3) "variables `tuple`i''"
    kappa `tuple`i''
}
```

How you get the variables names together to feed them into `tuples` will depend on the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation on the helpful answer by @Matthijs, but it really won't fit well into a comment. The main extra twists are

1. The use of `tokenize` to avoid repeated use of `word` # `of`. After `tokenize` the separate words of the argument (here separate variable names) are held in macros 1 up. Thus `tokenize a b c` puts `a` in local macro 1, `b` in local macro 2 and `c` in local macro 3. Nested macro references are treated exactly like parenthesised expressions in elementary algebra; what is on the inside is evaluated first.
2. Focusing directly on part of the notional matrix of results on one side of the diagonal. The small trick is to ensure that one matrix subscript exceeds the other subscript.

Random normal input doesn't make sense for `kap`, but you will be using your own data any way.

```
clear
set obs 100
local vars j_r_hp j_p_hp j_m_hp p_c_hp p_r_hp p_p_hp p_m_hp
foreach var of local vars   {
    gen `var' = rnormal()
}

tokenize `vars'  
local p : word count `vars'  
local pm1 = `p' - 1

forval i = 1/`pm1'   {
    local ip1 = `i' + 1 
    forval j = `ip1'/`p'   {
        di "``i'' and ``j''" 
        kap ``i'' ``j'' 
        di  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I might add my own answer in addition to highlight a few things.

The first thing to note is that for a new user, the most "straightforward" way to do it would likely involve hard-coding all variables into a `local` to use in a loop (as other answers suggest), or referencing them using a wildcard and writing more than one loop for each group. See the example below on how you might use a wildcard:

```
clear *
sysuse auto

/* Rename variables to match your .dta file and identify groups */
rename (price mpg rep78) (j_r_hp j_p_hp j_m_hp)
rename (headroom trunk weight) (p_c_hp p_r_hp p_m_hp)
rename (length turn displacement foreign) (z_r_hp z_m_hp z_p_hp z_c_hp)

/* Loop over all variables beginning with j and ending hp */
foreach x of varlist j*hp {
    foreach i of varlist j*hp {
        if "`x'" != "`i'" & "`i'" >= "`x'"{    // This section ensures you get only 
                                               // unique pairs of x & i
            kap `x' `i'
        }
    }
} 

/* Loop over all variables beginning with p and ending hp */
foreach x of varlist p*hp {
    * something involving x 
}
* etc.
```

Now, depending on how many groups you have or how many variables you have, this might not seem straightforward after all.

This brings up the second thing I would like to mention. In cases where hard-coding many variables or many repeated commands becomes cumbersome, I tend to favor a programmatic solution. This will often involve writing more code up front, but in many cases tends to be at least quasi-generalizable, and will allow you to easily evaluate hundreds of variables if you ever have the need without having to write them all out.

The code below uses the returned results from `describe`, along with some `foreach` loops and some extended macro functions to execute the `kappa` command over your variables without having to store them in a `local` manually.

```
clear *
sysuse auto

rename (price mpg rep78) (j_r_hp j_p_hp j_m_hp)
rename (headroom trunk weight) (p_c_hp p_r_hp p_m_hp)
rename (length turn displacement foreign) (z_r_hp z_m_hp z_p_hp z_c_hp)


/*
use gear_ratio as an arbitrary weight, order it first to easily extract
from the local containing varlist
*/
order gear_ratio, first 


qui describe, varlist
local Varlist `r(varlist)'            // store varlist in a local macro

preserve                              // preserve data so canges can be reverted back

foreach x of local Varlist {
    capture confirm numeric variable `x'
    if _rc {
        drop `x'                      // Keep only numeric variables to use in kappa 
    }
}

qui describe, varlist                 // replace the local macro varlist with now numeric only variables
local Varlist `r(varlist)'

local vars : list Varlist - weight    // remove weight from analysis varlist 

foreach x of local vars {
    foreach i of local vars  {
        if "`x'" != "`i'" & "`i'" >= "`x'"  {
            gettoken leftx : x, parse("_")
            gettoken lefti : i, parse("_")
            if "`leftx'" == "`lefti'" {
                kap `x' `i'
            }
        }
    }
}

restore
```

There of course will be a learning curve here for new users but I've found the use of macros, loops and returned results to be wonderfully effective in adding flexibility to my programs and do files - I would highly suggest anybody using Stata at least studies the basics of these three topics.

Comment: You are going to need `" "` in there for the comparison of variable names. If this is executing without error, it's for the wrong reason, namely that the values of two variables are being compared, not their names.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about these lines: `if 'x' != 'i' & 'i' >= 'x'`?

Comment: Quite so; variable names, not values [of first observations].

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how I missed that originally. Thanks for pointing it out.